# JButtons not appearing properly with borderlayout, also, issues adding actionListener to buttons

Tags: java, swing, events, jbutton, actionlistener

I've got 2 issues here with the same code, firstly, for some reason, the JButtons do not appear on the GUI with the current configuration, but the code is run (debugger does appear at that line of code).  I can't seem to figure out what's the issue.

The second issue I have is that JButton.addActionListener(this) doesn't like to work, and I need the actionListener to fire an event in a different class so I can't do the anonymous actionListener.

Here's the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PPP extends JFrame{  
    static digit atp_hundred = new digit();  //Amount to pay
    static digit atp_ten = new digit();
    static digit atp_unit = new digit();
    static digit atp_tenth = new digit();
    static digit atp_hundreth = new digit(); 
    static digit ltr_ten = new digit();     //Litres
    static digit ltr_unit = new digit();
    static digit ltr_tenth = new digit();
    static digit ppl_hundred = new digit(); //Pence per litre
    static digit ppl_ten = new digit();
    static digit ppl_unit = new digit();
    static digit ppl_tenth = new digit();
    static PPP frame = new PPP();   

    public static void init() {           
        frame.setSize(1280,800);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel mainPanel = new mainPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]){
        init();
        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                atp_hundred.value = i;
                atp_hundred.update();
                frame.getContentPane().repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                frame.getContentPane().repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void refresh() {
        repaint();
    }

    public PPP(){
        super();
    }

    /*public void update(Graphics g) {
    paint(g);
    }*/

    public static void atpCreate(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        atp_hundred.create(x, y);
        drawPolygons(g, atp_hundred);
        atp_ten.create(x+50,y);
        drawPolygons(g, atp_ten);
        atp_unit.create(x+100, y);
        drawPolygons(g, atp_unit);
        g.drawOval(x+145, y+60, 10,10);
        atp_tenth.create(x+160, y);
        drawPolygons(g, atp_tenth);
    }

    public static void ltrCreate(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        ltr_ten.create(x+50, y);
        drawPolygons(g, ltr_ten);
        ltr_unit.create(x+100, y);
        drawPolygons(g, ltr_unit);
        g.drawOval(x+145, y+60, 10, 10);
        ltr_tenth.create(x+160, y);
        drawPolygons(g, ltr_tenth);
    }

    public static void pplCreate(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        ppl_hundred.create(x, y);
        drawPolygons(g, ppl_hundred);
        ppl_ten.create(x+50,y);
        drawPolygons(g, ppl_ten);
        ppl_unit.create(x+100, y);
        drawPolygons(g, ppl_unit);
        g.drawOval(x+145, y+60, 10,10);
        ppl_tenth.create(x+160, y);
        drawPolygons(g, ppl_tenth);
    }

    public static void drawPolygons(Graphics g, digit d) {
        if (d.top) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillPolygon(d.ptop);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawPolygon(d.ptop);
        }
        if (d.topleft) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillPolygon(d.ptopleft);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawPolygon(d.ptopleft);
        }
        if (d.topright) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillPolygon(d.ptopright);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawPolygon(d.ptopright);
        }
        if (d.mid) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillPolygon(d.pmid);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawPolygon(d.pmid);
        }
        if (d.botleft) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillPolygon(d.pbotleft);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawPolygon(d.pbotleft);
        }
        if (d.botright) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillPolygon(d.pbotright);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawPolygon(d.pbotright);
        }
        if (d.bot) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillPolygon(d.pbot);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawPolygon(d.pbot);
        }  
        g.setColor(Color.black);
    }
}
class mainPanel extends JPanel {
    public mainPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280,800));
        JPanel customerPanel = new customerPanel();
        customerPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(customerPanel);
        //add(new customerButtons());
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setFont(new Font("Copperplate Gothic Light", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        String title = "Pete's Petrol Pump Simulation vAlpha0.1";
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        //g.clearRect(0,0,640,500);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(title, (int)(640 - (g.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(title, g).getWidth() / 2)), 75);
    }
}
class customerPanel extends JPanel {
    public customerPanel() {
        //setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640,500));
        //setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,800));
        customerButtons buttons = new customerButtons();
        add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        //super.paintComponent(g);
        /*g.setFont(new Font("Copperplate Gothic Light", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        String title = "Pete's Petrol Pump Simulation vAlpha0.1";
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.clearRect(0,0,640,500);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(title, (int)(640 - (g.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(title, g).getWidth() / 2)), 75);*/
        g.drawRoundRect(20,100,600,250,5,5);
        g.setFont(new Font("Gill Sans MT", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        g.drawString("Amount to Pay: ", 40, 160);
        PPP.atpCreate(g, 200, 110);
        g.drawString("Litres Dispensed: ", 40, 240);
        PPP.ltrCreate(g, 200, 190);
        g.drawString("Pence per Litre: ", 40, 320);
        PPP.pplCreate(g, 200, 270);
        //System.out.println((g.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds("Amount to Pay", g).getWidth()));
    }
}
class customerButtons extends JPanel {
    public customerButtons() {
        JButton remove = new JButton("Remove nozzle");
        remove.setActionCommand("remove");
        //System.out.println("Hello");
        remove.addActionListener(this);
        remove.setToolTipText("Replace the fucking nozzle");
        JButton squeeze = new JButton("Squeeze nozzle");
        squeeze.setActionCommand("squeeze");
        squeeze.addActionListener(this);
        squeeze.setToolTipText("Squeeze the fucking nozzle");
        JButton stop = new JButton("Stop Squeeze");
        stop.setActionCommand("stop");
        stop.addActionListener(this);
        stop.setToolTipText("Stop squeezing the fucking nozzle");
        JButton replace = new JButton("Replace nozzle");
        replace.setActionCommand("replace");
        replace.addActionListener(this);
        replace.setToolTipText("Replace the fucking nozzle");
        add(remove);
        add(squeeze);
        add(stop);
        add(replace);

    }
}

class digit {
    int value = 0;
    boolean top = false;
    boolean topleft = false;
    boolean topright = false;
    boolean mid = false;
    boolean botleft = false;
    boolean botright = false;
    boolean bot = false;
    public void update() {
        switch(value) {
            case 0: top = true;
            topleft = true;
            topright = true;
            mid = false;
            botleft = true;
            botright = true;
            bot = true;
            break;
            case 1: top = false;
            topleft = false;
            topright = true;
            mid = false;
            botleft = false;
            botright = true;
            bot = false;
            break;
            case 2: top = true;
            topleft = false;
            topright = true;
            mid = true;
            botleft = true;
            botright = false;
            bot = true;
            break;
            case 3: top = true;
            topleft = false;
            topright = true;
            mid = true;
            botleft = false;
            botright = true;
            bot = true;
            break;
            case 4: top = false;
            topleft = true;
            topright = true;
            mid = true;
            botleft = false;
            botright = true;
            bot = false;
            break;
            case 5: top = true;
            topleft = true;
            topright = false;
            mid = true;
            botleft = false;
            botright = true;
            bot = true;
            break;
            case 6: top = true;
            topleft = true;
            topright = false;
            mid = true;
            botleft = true;
            botright = true;
            bot = true;
            break;
            case 7: top = true;
            topleft = false;
            topright = true;
            mid = false;
            botleft = false;
            botright = true;
            bot = false;
            break;
            case 8: top = true;
            topleft = true;
            topright = true;
            mid = true;
            botleft = true;
            botright = true;
            bot = true;
            break;
            case 9: top = true;
            topleft = true;
            topright = true;
            mid = true;
            botleft = false;
            botright = true;
            bot = true;
            break;                    
        }
    }
    Polygon ptop = new Polygon();
    Polygon ptopleft = new Polygon();
    Polygon ptopright = new Polygon();
    Polygon pmid = new Polygon();
    Polygon pbotleft = new Polygon();
    Polygon pbotright = new Polygon();
    Polygon pbot = new Polygon();
    public void create(int x, int y) {
        ptop.addPoint(x+10, y);
        ptop.addPoint(x+30, y);
        ptop.addPoint(x+35, y+5);
        ptop.addPoint(x+30, y+10);
        ptop.addPoint(x+10, y+10);
        ptop.addPoint(x+5, y+5);
        ptopleft.addPoint(x+5, y+5);
        ptopleft.addPoint(x+10, y+10);
        ptopleft.addPoint(x+10, y+30);
        ptopleft.addPoint(x+5, y+35);
        ptopleft.addPoint(x, y+30);
        ptopleft.addPoint(x, y+10);   
        ptopright.addPoint(x+35, y+5);
        ptopright.addPoint(x+40, y+10);
        ptopright.addPoint(x+40, y+30);
        ptopright.addPoint(x+35, y+35);
        ptopright.addPoint(x+30, y+30);
        ptopright.addPoint(x+30, y+10);     
        pmid.addPoint(x+10, y+30);
        pmid.addPoint(x+30, y+30);
        pmid.addPoint(x+35, y+35);
        pmid.addPoint(x+30, y+40);
        pmid.addPoint(x+10, y+40);
        pmid.addPoint(x+5, y+35);  
        pbotleft.addPoint(x+5, y+35);
        pbotleft.addPoint(x+10, y+40);
        pbotleft.addPoint(x+10, y+60);
        pbotleft.addPoint(x+5, y+65);
        pbotleft.addPoint(x, y+60);
        pbotleft.addPoint(x, y+40);
        pbotright.addPoint(x+35, y+35);
        pbotright.addPoint(x+40, y+40);
        pbotright.addPoint(x+40, y+60);
        pbotright.addPoint(x+35, y+65);
        pbotright.addPoint(x+30, y+60);
        pbotright.addPoint(x+30, y+40);            
        pbot.addPoint(x+10, y+60);
        pbot.addPoint(x+30, y+60);
        pbot.addPoint(x+35, y+65);
        pbot.addPoint(x+30, y+70);
        pbot.addPoint(x+10, y+70);
        pbot.addPoint(x+5, y+65);          
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: without Thread.sleep(1000/10); is life easier, 1. use Swing Timer instead, 2. for way reasons are there two sleeps, 3. use JFrame.(re)validate and JFrame.repaint()

Comment: `static digit atp_h..`  Why `static`?  Using the `static` modifier is usually a sign of broken design.

Comment: Get rid of the while loop and use a Swing Timer, you risk block the EDT

Answer (score 2):

1. You have used layout wrongly. You are adding `components` before setting a `layout` to your `panel`
   For your first question my suggesion is Read [LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)
2. Now for the second Question:
   Where is your `ActionListener`? See the modified code. I have added it.

[image]

Modified code

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class PPP extends JFrame{  
    static digit atp_hundred = new digit();  //Amount to pay
    static digit atp_ten = new digit();
    static digit atp_unit = new digit();
    static digit atp_tenth = new digit();
    static digit atp_hundreth = new digit(); 
    static digit ltr_ten = new digit();     //Litres
    static digit ltr_unit = new digit();
    static digit ltr_tenth = new digit();
    static digit ppl_hundred = new digit(); //Pence per litre
    static digit ppl_ten = new digit();
    static digit ppl_unit = new digit();
    static digit ppl_tenth = new digit();
    static PPP frame = new PPP();   

    public static void init() {           
        frame.setSize(1280,800);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel mainPanel = new mainPanel();
        mainPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2));
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
                public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            });
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]){
        init();
        while (true) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                atp_hundred.value = i;
                atp_hundred.update();
                frame.getContentPane().repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                frame.getContentPane().repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void refresh() {
        repaint();
    }

    public PPP(){
        super();
    }

    /*public void update(Graphics g) {
    paint(g);
    }*/

    public static void atpCreate(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        atp_hundred.create(x, y);
        drawPolygons(g, atp_hundred);
        atp_ten.create(x+50,y);
        drawPolygons(g, atp_ten);
        atp_unit.create(x+100, y);
        drawPolygons(g, atp_unit);
        g.drawOval(x+145, y+60, 10,10);
        atp_tenth.create(x+160, y);
        drawPolygons(g, atp_tenth);
    }

    public static void ltrCreate(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        ltr_ten.create(x+50, y);
        drawPolygons(g, ltr_ten);
        ltr_unit.create(x+100, y);
        drawPolygons(g, ltr_unit);
        g.drawOval(x+145, y+60, 10, 10);
        ltr_tenth.create(x+160, y);
        drawPolygons(g, ltr_tenth);
    }

    public static void pplCreate(Graphics g, int x, int y) {
        ppl_hundred.create(x, y);
        drawPolygons(g, ppl_hundred);
        ppl_ten.create(x+50,y);
        drawPolygons(g, ppl_ten);
        ppl_unit.create(x+100, y);
        drawPolygons(g, ppl_unit);
        g.drawOval(x+145, y+60, 10,10);
        ppl_tenth.create(x+160, y);
        drawPolygons(g, ppl_tenth);
    }

    public static void drawPolygons(Graphics g, digit d) {
        if (d.top) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillPolygon(d.ptop);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawPolygon(d.ptop);
        }
        if (d.topleft) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillPolygon(d.ptopleft);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawPolygon(d.ptopleft);
        }
        if (d.topright) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillPolygon(d.ptopright);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawPolygon(d.ptopright);
        }
        if (d.mid) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillPolygon(d.pmid);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawPolygon(d.pmid);
        }
        if (d.botleft) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillPolygon(d.pbotleft);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawPolygon(d.pbotleft);
        }
        if (d.botright) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillPolygon(d.pbotright);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawPolygon(d.pbotright);
        }
        if (d.bot) {
            g.setColor(Color.green);
            g.fillPolygon(d.pbot);
        } else {
            g.setColor(Color.black);
            g.drawPolygon(d.pbot);
        }  
        g.setColor(Color.black);
    }
}
class mainPanel extends JPanel {
    public mainPanel() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1280,800));
        JPanel customerPanel = new customerPanel();

        add(customerPanel);
        //add(new customerButtons());
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setFont(new Font("Copperplate Gothic Light", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        String title = "Pete's Petrol Pump Simulation vAlpha0.1";
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        //g.clearRect(0,0,640,500);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(title, (int)(640 - (g.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(title, g).getWidth() / 2)), 75);
    }
}
class customerPanel extends JPanel {
    public customerPanel() {
        //setPreferredSize(new Dimension(640,500));
        //setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,800));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        customerButtons buttons = new customerButtons();
        add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        //super.paintComponent(g);
        /*g.setFont(new Font("Copperplate Gothic Light", Font.PLAIN, 30));
        String title = "Pete's Petrol Pump Simulation vAlpha0.1";
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.clearRect(0,0,640,500);
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.drawString(title, (int)(640 - (g.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(title, g).getWidth() / 2)), 75);*/
        g.drawRoundRect(20,100,600,250,5,5);
        g.setFont(new Font("Gill Sans MT", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        g.drawString("Amount to Pay: ", 40, 160);
        PPP.atpCreate(g, 200, 110);
        g.drawString("Litres Dispensed: ", 40, 240);
        PPP.ltrCreate(g, 200, 190);
        g.drawString("Pence per Litre: ", 40, 320);
        PPP.pplCreate(g, 200, 270);
        //System.out.println((g.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds("Amount to Pay", g).getWidth()));
    }
}
class customerButtons extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    public customerButtons() {
        JButton remove = new JButton("Remove nozzle");
        remove.setActionCommand("remove");
        //System.out.println("Hello");
        remove.addActionListener(this);
        remove.setToolTipText("Replace the fucking nozzle");
        JButton squeeze = new JButton("Squeeze nozzle");
        squeeze.setActionCommand("squeeze");
        squeeze.addActionListener(this);
        squeeze.setToolTipText("Squeeze the fucking nozzle");
        JButton stop = new JButton("Stop Squeeze");
        stop.setActionCommand("stop");
        stop.addActionListener(this);
        stop.setToolTipText("Stop squeezing the fucking nozzle");
        JButton replace = new JButton("Replace nozzle");
        replace.setActionCommand("replace");
        replace.addActionListener(this);
        replace.setToolTipText("Replace the fucking nozzle");
        add(remove);
        add(squeeze);
        add(stop);
        add(replace);

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do your stuff here

    }
}

class digit {
    int value = 0;
    boolean top = false;
    boolean topleft = false;
    boolean topright = false;
    boolean mid = false;
    boolean botleft = false;
    boolean botright = false;
    boolean bot = false;
    public void update() {
        switch(value) {
            case 0: top = true;
            topleft = true;
            topright = true;
            mid = false;
            botleft = true;
            botright = true;
            bot = true;
            break;
            case 1: top = false;
            topleft = false;
            topright = true;
            mid = false;
            botleft = false;
            botright = true;
            bot = false;
            break;
            case 2: top = true;
            topleft = false;
            topright = true;
            mid = true;
            botleft = true;
            botright = false;
            bot = true;
            break;
            case 3: top = true;
            topleft = false;
            topright = true;
            mid = true;
            botleft = false;
            botright = true;
            bot = true;
            break;
            case 4: top = false;
            topleft = true;
            topright = true;
            mid = true;
            botleft = false;
            botright = true;
            bot = false;
            break;
            case 5: top = true;
            topleft = true;
            topright = false;
            mid = true;
            botleft = false;
            botright = true;
            bot = true;
            break;
            case 6: top = true;
            topleft = true;
            topright = false;
            mid = true;
            botleft = true;
            botright = true;
            bot = true;
            break;
            case 7: top = true;
            topleft = false;
            topright = true;
            mid = false;
            botleft = false;
            botright = true;
            bot = false;
            break;
            case 8: top = true;
            topleft = true;
            topright = true;
            mid = true;
            botleft = true;
            botright = true;
            bot = true;
            break;
            case 9: top = true;
            topleft = true;
            topright = true;
            mid = true;
            botleft = false;
            botright = true;
            bot = true;
            break;                    
        }
    }
    Polygon ptop = new Polygon();
    Polygon ptopleft = new Polygon();
    Polygon ptopright = new Polygon();
    Polygon pmid = new Polygon();
    Polygon pbotleft = new Polygon();
    Polygon pbotright = new Polygon();
    Polygon pbot = new Polygon();
    public void create(int x, int y) {
        ptop.addPoint(x+10, y);
        ptop.addPoint(x+30, y);
        ptop.addPoint(x+35, y+5);
        ptop.addPoint(x+30, y+10);
        ptop.addPoint(x+10, y+10);
        ptop.addPoint(x+5, y+5);
        ptopleft.addPoint(x+5, y+5);
        ptopleft.addPoint(x+10, y+10);
        ptopleft.addPoint(x+10, y+30);
        ptopleft.addPoint(x+5, y+35);
        ptopleft.addPoint(x, y+30);
        ptopleft.addPoint(x, y+10);   
        ptopright.addPoint(x+35, y+5);
        ptopright.addPoint(x+40, y+10);
        ptopright.addPoint(x+40, y+30);
        ptopright.addPoint(x+35, y+35);
        ptopright.addPoint(x+30, y+30);
        ptopright.addPoint(x+30, y+10);     
        pmid.addPoint(x+10, y+30);
        pmid.addPoint(x+30, y+30);
        pmid.addPoint(x+35, y+35);
        pmid.addPoint(x+30, y+40);
        pmid.addPoint(x+10, y+40);
        pmid.addPoint(x+5, y+35);  
        pbotleft.addPoint(x+5, y+35);
        pbotleft.addPoint(x+10, y+40);
        pbotleft.addPoint(x+10, y+60);
        pbotleft.addPoint(x+5, y+65);
        pbotleft.addPoint(x, y+60);
        pbotleft.addPoint(x, y+40);
        pbotright.addPoint(x+35, y+35);
        pbotright.addPoint(x+40, y+40);
        pbotright.addPoint(x+40, y+60);
        pbotright.addPoint(x+35, y+65);
        pbotright.addPoint(x+30, y+60);
        pbotright.addPoint(x+30, y+40);            
        pbot.addPoint(x+10, y+60);
        pbot.addPoint(x+30, y+60);
        pbot.addPoint(x+35, y+65);
        pbot.addPoint(x+30, y+70);
        pbot.addPoint(x+10, y+70);
        pbot.addPoint(x+5, y+65);          
    }
}
```

But in this case try to create a layout like below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## 1

Regarding the button does not appearing issue, you are setting the layout of each panel (CustomerPanel and MainPanel) after adding the components to it. Please try by setting Layout before adding 
components. example

`setLayout(new BorderLayout());
customerButtons buttons = new customerButtons();
add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);`

## 2

Regarding the ActionListener issue, Can you please check that you implement ActionListener in your code. I cannot find an [Actionlistener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html).